# XSD with strict combination

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

i have a little problem with an exisiting XSD and an additional rule I want to implement. Here's a part of my original XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="action">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="actid" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="acttyp" type="acttype" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="acttype">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="type1" />
        <xs:enumeration value="type2" />
        <xs:enumeration value="type3" />
        <xs:enumeration value="type4" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

So you see there are actions with different actiontypes I defined. Now there is a new rule, if there is a special actid, let's take "123", than there is only type1 permitted.
So to show you:

```
<action actid="123" acttype="type1">   =  permitted
<action actid="234" acttype="type1">   =  permitted
<action actid="234" acttype="type2">   =  permitted
<action actid="123" acttype="type2">   =  forbidden
```

Is there a way to do this with xsd? I don't know how to combinate the enum with that rule. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  **XSD 1.1**, it can be done using `xs:assert`.

```
<xs:assert test="if (@actid = '123') then @acttyp = 'type1' else true()"/>.
```

your XSD code should be rewritten as follow:

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:complexType name="action">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="actid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="acttyp" type="acttype" use="required"/>
                <xs:assert
                    test="
                        if (@actid = '123') then
                            @acttyp = 'type1'
                        else
                            true()"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="acttype">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="type1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="type2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="type3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="type4"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="e" type="action"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hello Kachna and thanks for your answer, looks quite good to me, but I get an error with your XSD.

s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'action' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

I think the problem is our XSD-Parser version. Unfortunately we neither have XSD 1.1 Parser nor Xpath 2.0 support in our project and I'm also not authorized to change this. Is there a way to do the same with XSD 1.0?